# N-queen Chess Final Horizontal Validation using python

Tags: python, chess, n-queens

I am trying to solve the n-queen validation problem where the user first prints an n by n matrix for our sake, 8 by 8 from 0 - 63. The user keys in the Position of the queens then our model evaluates whether they are attacking each other. I fail to get through the second test case when queen input  =  " 59 24 41 19 52 13 30 47 " where clearly 41 and 47 See Q on the same row. The program should automatically produce a "FAIL" as two queens on the same row attack each other. Below is my code and required output :

```
# Get the size of the board from the user.
n = int(input("n: "))

# Print the board with numbers.
s =''
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        z = i * n + j
        
        if j != 0:
            s += ' '
        
        if z < 10:
            s += ' '
        s += str(z)
    
    if i != j:
        s += '\n'
print(s)
# Get the queens from the user.
queens = list(map(int, input("Queens: ").split()))

# Print the board with queens.

s =''
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        z = i * n + j
        
        if j != 0:
            s += ' '
        
        if z < 10:
            if z in queens:
                z = " Q"
            else:
                s += ' '
        elif z > 10:
            if z in queens:
                z = " Q"
            else:
                s +=""
        s += str(z)
    
    if i != j:
        s += '\n'
print(s)
# Check if the queens are in the same row or diagonal.
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        try:
            if queens[i] == queens[j]:
                print("FAIL")
                exit()
            if abs(queens[i] - queens[j]) == abs(i-j):
                print("FAIL")
                exit()
        except IndexError:
            pass

# If the queens are not in the same row or diagonal, print success.
print("--> SUCCESS <--")
```

[image]

What do I need to edit to produce a correct output? Code refactoring is appreciated

Comment: @Alexander . Explain ?

Comment: Sorry I was in the middle of writing an answer but something came up... if it still isn't answered when I come back I will explain

Comment: try using these numbers as input ->  `[0, 16, 9, 7, 22, 18, 2, 12]`  Maybe that will help a little

Comment: you might also notice that in your example there are also 2 queens on line with index = 3.  and there are 2 queens in the bottom 2 lines that are diagonal to each other.  and the first queen on line 5 and the queen on the last line are also diagonal to each other.  After noticing all of this I think giving you the answer would be a disservice to you.  I suggest starting over and thinking of a new strategy

Comment: also there are 2 queens in column with index 3, and the first queen on line 5 is diagonal to the queen on line 1.  The fact that your algorithm didn't catch any of those means you need a new strategy

Comment: @Alexander...just trying to pass an assignment lol with 2-hour deadline.  An answer now then I rethink it over again would help :) :)...Irregardless, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`abs(queens[i] - queens[j]) == abs(i-j)` is not a correct check. The *index* in the queens list is of no importance. If you would shuffle the input list, the result should not be impacted. Yet, with `abs(i-j)` this comparison gives a significance to how far apart two queen positions are in the input list.

To verify if two queens are in the same row, you should first extract the row from a given position. For that you can use division by 8:

```
queens[i] // 8 == queens[j] // 8
```

If this comparison is true, then both queens are on the same row. A similar thing can be done to check if two queens share the same column:

```
queens[i] % 8 == queens[j] % 8
```

For diagonal checks, you should compare the sum of a position's row and column (for one type of diagonal) or the difference of a position's row and column.

Thus it makes sense to first extract from all positions the rows and the columns, and then continue from there.

You could also count the *distinct* number of position rows and check there are  distinct rows occupied. Same for columns and for diagonals. To get *distinct* values, you can create a `set` (which can only store unique values, ignoring duplicates). If the set has fewer values than , you know there is a duplicate.

You should also check that each position is an integer between 0 and ² (excluded).

Here is all that combined in a function:

```
def verify(n, queens):
    if any(queen not in range(n*n) for queen in queens):
        return False  # invalid queen position
    rows = [queen // n for queen in queens]
    cols = [queen % n  for queen in queens]
    if len(set(rows)) != n:
        return False  # multiple queens on same row
    if len(set(cols)) != n:
        return False  # multiple queens on same column
    if len(set((i + j for i, j in zip(rows, cols)))) != n:
        return False  # multiple queens on same backward diagonal (\\)
    if len(set((i - j for i, j in zip(rows, cols)))) != n:
        return False  # multiple queens on same forward diagonal (/)"
    return True
```

You could use that as follows:

```
def boardstr(n, queens):
    return "\n".join(
        "".join(("Q" if z in queens else str(z)).rjust(3) for z in range(i, i + n))
        for i in range(0, n*n, n)
    )

def verify(n, queens):
    if len(queens) != n:
        return False  # number of queens is wrong
    if any(queen not in range(n*n) for queen in queens):
        return False  # invalid queen position
    rows = [queen // n for queen in queens]
    cols = [queen % n  for queen in queens]
    if len(set(rows)) != n:
        return False  # multiple queens on same row
    if len(set(cols)) != n:
        return False  # multiple queens on same column
    if len(set((i + j for i, j in zip(rows, cols)))) != n:
        return False  # multiple queens on same backward diagonal (\\)
    if len(set((i - j for i, j in zip(rows, cols)))) != n:
        return False  # multiple queens on same forward diagonal (/)"
    return True

n = int(input("n: "))
print(boardstr(n, []))
queens = list(map(int, input("Queens: ").split()))
print(boardstr(n, queens))
valid = verify(n, queens)
print("--> SUCCESS <--" if valid else "--> FAIL <--")
```